# wordpress - Insert posts programmatically while maintaining links

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, migration

I am currently working on a migration script to insert articles from XML into Wordpress.

So far I parsed the XML and created arrays in PHP, I am looping through these arrays and insert them all one by one into Wordpress with the following code:

```
$post = array(
            'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags($article['title']),
            'post_content'  => $article['description'],
            'post_status'   => 'publish',
            'post_author'   => 1,
            'ping_status'   => 'closed',
            'post_date'     => $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
            'post_type'     => $post_type
        );

        $result = wp_insert_post($post);
```

That all goes well, however here comes the issue: the XML's are an export from a website (unfortunately I do not know which CMS ) and in the content there can be links to files on the same site, for example:

```
<![CDATA[<p><strong>Shortcuts:</strong></p>
<p/>
<ul>
<li><a href="http://www.testsite.fi/julkaisut/5440/julkaisut?contentPath=fi/julkaisut/esitteet/elakkeen_hakeminen_ulkomailta">(Booklet in Finnish)</a> 
</li>
<li><a href="http://www.testsite.fi/julkaisut/5440/julkaisut?contentPath=fi/julkaisut/esitteet/sa_har_soker_du_pension_fran_utlandet">(Booklet in Swedish)</a> 
</li>
<li><a href="http://www.testsite.fi/julkaisut/5440/julkaisut?contentPath=fi/julkaisut/esitteet/pensioni_taotlemine_valismaalt">(Booklet in Estonian)</a> 
</li>
<li><a href="http://www.testsite.fi/julkaisut/5440/julkaisut?contentPath=fi/julkaisut/esitteet/poluchenie_pensii_iz_drugih_stran">(Booklet in Russian)</a> 
</li>
</ul>]]>
```

Testsite.fi is my own site, so these are internal links.

Those links are referring to PDF's and this should be inserted into wordpress, but obviously the links will be different. I do have the PDF's that are being referred to ( for example: elakkeen_hakeminen_ulkomailta.pdf, and they are in same folder as this script is ) so all that is required is to upload this file in Wordpress programmatically or manually move it to the correct location, and then update the links so that it still works.

Any clue how to do this? I am guessing something with regular expressions, but can't really figure it out.

Comment: You can copy file into the upload folder, they will be accessible. It's only that Wordpress doesn't yet know about them, but you're in control of the location. And perhaps with some of the file api, codex should offer some options. And you don't parse that HTML-fragment with regex, just with DOMDocument. Allows you to change the links as well.

Comment: Thanks, got the upload part figured out now. Just not sure yet about the DOMDocument, not really familiar with this.

Comment: I think here is a similar example on how to parse HTML and change URLs: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24350166/367456

Comment: The urls in the above example do not have a filetype... is it intentional? Moreover do you only want to change links to pdfs or do you want to change all internal links?

Comment: @alpipego: unfortunately that is how we got the links, I know in this case that they happen to be PDFs. Yes, we would like to change all the internal links.

Comment: @hakre: thanks, I will take a look at that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change all internal links you can use this:

```
$content = preg_replace('%href="http://www\.testsite\.fi/(.*)"%', 'href="' get_bloginfo('wpurl') . '/$1"', $article['description'], -1);

$post = array(
    'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags($article['title']),
    'post_content'  => $content,
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'post_author'   => 1,
    'ping_status'   => 'closed',
    'post_date'     => $dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
    'post_type'     => $post_type
);

$result = wp_insert_post($post);
```

Since the pdfs in your example do not have a filetype they can't be identified programmatically. Otherwise it would be something along the lines of:

```
$upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
$content = preg_replace('%href="http://www\.testsite\.fi/(.*)/(.*).pdf"%', 'href="' . $upload_dir['url'] . '/$2.pdf"', $article['description'], -1);
```

where `$2` is the filename for the pdf.

Note:

The `href` part in the regex is not neccesary but assures that you are not changing urls that are not inside a `href` atrribute. Depending on the scenario you can leave that part out.