# wordpress php code to display image from db inside array using post_content call

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, plugins

I am trying to fetch an image from mysql db using wordpress  through php coding. I am able to fetch the url path but image is not displayed . I want to display the image along with the description and title but i am getting combined result without formatting.

```
 foreach ( $database_results as $result ) {
          
  $car_model = array(
      
        'post_name'=>wp_strip_all_tags($result->Color),
        'post_content' => wp_strip_all_tags($result->title.' '. $result->descriptions.''."<?php echo '<img src='.$result->image.'/>' ?>"),
        
        
        'post_title' => wp_strip_all_tags( $result->Brand  . ' ' . $result->Model . ' ' . $result->Km ),
        'meta_input' => array(
            'id'        => $result->id,
            'brand'        => $result->Brand,
            'model'        => $result->Model,
            'color'        => $result->Color,
            'km'           => $result->Km,
        ),
        'post_type'   => 'auto',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        
    
         
    );
     
    wp_insert_post( $car_model );
}
```

This is my sql database table

`describe wp_garage;`

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | int | YES |  | NULL |  |
| image | blob | YES |  | NULL |  |
| Brand | text | YES |  | NULL |  |
| Model | text | YES |  | NULL |  |
| title | text | YES |  | NULL |  |
| descriptions | mediumtext | YES |  | NULL |  |
| Color | text | YES |  | NULL |  |
| Km | int | YES |  | NULL |  |

```sql
insert into wp_garage value("5644","https://static.toiimg.com/thumb/msid-79720359,width-1070,height-580,imgsize-78661,resizemode-75,overlay-toi_sw,pt-32,y_pad-40/photo.jpg","p","p","my name","wordpress","green","12");
```

`Query OK, 1 row affected (0.01 sec)`
[image]

Comment: Can check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31870958/wordpress-insert-posts-programmatically-while-maintaining-links

Comment: i have tried but i didnot get expected output